# Finding the initial conditions of a conservation law hyperbolic system?

Tags: waves, computational-physics

Consider $u(\boldsymbol{x},t)$ to be a function that is known at $t=0 $ by the initial conditions

$$u(\boldsymbol{x},0)= f(\boldsymbol{x}),\quad u_t(\boldsymbol{x},0)= g(\boldsymbol{x})$$
Where $\boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ 
Let $q, r, s$ be functions such that
\begin{align*}
    &q_t= cu_x  \\
    &r_t= cu_y  \\
    &s_t= cu_z  \\
    &u_t =cq_x+ cr_y+ cs_z
\end{align*}
Then, apparently, up to a constant, we can determine $q(\boldsymbol{x},0),\ r(\boldsymbol{x},0)$ and $s(\boldsymbol{x},0)$ at the initial time, in term of $f$ and $g$ . 
But I stuck at how to find that.

The question is : Can we determine these initial values ??

\ tentative :

We can notice that the system of equations can be looked at as two simple equations if we consider $v= (q,r,s)$ :
\begin{align*}
    &v_t= c\ \nabla u \\
    &u_t =c\ \nabla \cdot v
\end{align*}

Notice also, that for the one dimensional case:
\begin{align*}
    &q_t= cu_x \\
    &u_t =cq_x
\end{align*}
We can easily derive that
\begin{align*}
    &c\ q(x,t)= \int_{x_0}^x u_t(\xi,t)d\xi \\
\text{So that }\quad  & q(x,0)= \frac{1}{c}\int_{x_0}^x u_t(\xi,0)d\xi= \frac{1}{c}\int_{x_0}^x g(\xi)d\xi
\end{align*}
And we see that indeed in the one dimensional case $q(x,0)$ is known in term of $g$ up to a constant. So now the question is to do the same for the 3 dimensional case.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed already ! But I framed the question in the best way I believe, the question doesn't need necessarily to know that this system describe the wave equation, even though I tagged it ! Knowledge on the wave equation and related numerical schemes would definitely help giving an answer. The aim of the question is to initialize the Lax-Wendroff scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the spatial and temporal derivatives of $q,\,r,\,s$, you'll quickly find,
\begin{align}
  q_{tx} &= cu_{xx} \\
  r_{ty} &= cu_{yy} \\
  s_{tz} &= cu_{zz}
\end{align}
And if you then take the second temporal derivative of $u$, you can see pretty easily,
$$ u_{tt}=c\left(q_{x}+r_{y}+s_{z}\right)_t=c\left(q_{tx}+r_{ty}+s_{tz}\right)=c^2\left(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}\right)$$
which is to say that this is really just the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation). In one dimension, you will find that this is solved using [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula),
$$ u\left(x,t\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi.\tag{1}$$

In higher dimensions, this becomes known as [Kirchhoff's formula](https://web.math.utk.edu/%7Efreire/teaching/m435s14/WaveEquationExamples.pdf) (PDF link), which is a bit more complicated to derive, but more or less follows the same idea as the 1D case. You want to convert to spherical coordinate system and consider [spherical means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_mean), defining $U$, $F$ and $G$ such that,
\begin{align}
  U(x,r,t)&=\frac{1}{\vert\partial B(x,r)\vert}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(\xi,t)\mathrm dS_\xi \\
  F(x,r,t)&=\frac{1}{\vert\partial B(x,r)\vert}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}f(\xi,t)\mathrm dS_\xi \\
  G(x,r,t)&=\frac{1}{\vert\partial B(x,r)\vert}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}g(\xi,t)\mathrm dS_\xi
\end{align}
where $B$ is the [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)) in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\partial B$ the surface. To recover $u$ from this, we simply take the limit of $r\to0$,
$$u(x,t)=\lim_{r\to0}U(x,r,t)$$

If we then let $\bar{U}=rU$ and likewise for $F$ and $G$, then $\bar{U}$ satisfies the wave equation and has a solution similar to Eq (1),
$$\bar{U}(x,r,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\bar{F}(t+r)+\bar{F}(t-r)\right]+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t-r}^{t+r}\bar{G}(y)\mathrm dy $$
Taking the limit gives,
$$ u(x,t)=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\bar{U}}{r}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{t}{\vert\partial B\vert}\int_{\partial B}f(\xi)\mathrm dS_\xi\right)+\frac{t}{\vert\partial B\vert} \int_{\partial B}g(\xi)\mathrm dS_\xi.$$
With quite some more work, this can be reduced to what is called Kirchhoff's formula,
$$ u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\vert\partial B\vert}\int_{\partial B}\left[tg(\xi)+f(\xi)+\nabla f\cdot\left(\xi-x\right)\right]\,\mathrm dS_\xi$$

---

When solving the wave equation $\psi_{tt}=c^2\nabla^2\psi$, a common trick is to define variables $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ such that,
$$ p=c\psi_x,\quad q=c\psi_y,\quad r=c\psi_z,\quad s=\psi_t$$
and combine them into $u=\left[p,\,q,\,r,\,s\right]^T$ to form the evolution equation,
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\nabla F\tag{A.1}$$
where $F$ is flux in terms of the variables $p,\,q,\,r,\,s$. For instance,
\begin{align}
  p_t &= c\psi_{xt}=c\psi_{tx}=cs_x \\
  q_t &= c\psi_{ty}=cs_y \\
  r_t &= c\psi_{tz}=cs_z \\
  s_t &= cp_x+cq_y+cr_z
\end{align}
implies,
$$ F_x=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & -c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -c & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} p \\ q \\ r \\ s \end{array}\right) $$

I believe that what you are supposed to be doing is that, given the initial conditions $\psi(x,0)=f(x)$ and $\psi_t(x,0)=g(x)$, you apply these directly to the variables:
$$ p(x,0)=c\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\;q(x,0)=c\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\;r(x,0)=c\frac{\partial f}{\partial z},\;s(x,0)=g(x) $$
And integrate according to Eq (A.1) using Lax-Wendroff, rather than trying to apply Kirchhoff's formula to the equations.

Comment: While I am glad you found out this is about the wave equation, this doesn't answer my question, I am looking to implement a Lax-Wendroff scheme for this system, so I need to initialize $q,r$ and $s$, the two conditions for $u$ determines uniquely a solution, so there must be a way to convert these two conditions into conditions on $q,r$ and $s$

Comment: You have $u$ and definitions of $q,\,r,\,s$ in terms of $u$, wouldn't it just be applying derivatives?

Comment: That said, it seems to me that you could also just take $u(x,0)=f(x)$ & $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ and integrate $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ directly, bypassing $q,\,r,\,s$ altogether.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but we need not to bypass $q, r$ and $s$, as I said this is to run the Lax-Wendroff scheme, which runs time steps iterations starting from the time $t=0$, the equation is transformed to $U_t+AU_x+BU_y+CU_z= 0$ where $U= (u,q,r,s)$, which is a conservation law system.

Comment: You know $u$ from the last equation above (or at least it's supposedly determinable), so then integrating $q_t=cu_x$ would give you $q$ in terms of the $g$ and $f$; similarly for $r$ and $s$. That seems a lot harder to do than simply numerically evolving $u$ using the wave equation, but YMMV.

Comment: the question was closed ! why?? 
- @Kanos : I am not sure if you use Kirchhoff's formula usually to solve the wave equation in practical settings, but my take is that numerical computation is necessary in this formula as well (integration over the sphere), this is why numerical schemes for hyperbolic systems are various (FDM, FEM,...), one of the good finite volume schemes is the Lax-Wendroff, and to use this one we have to reduce the wave equation to its first order conservation law form I described above, and we need to initialize $q,r$ and $s$.

Comment: I've added an update that I think might help. I could be wrong, since I'm not seeing the problem statement given to you, but I suspect your starting point might be a little off, and the update should help with it.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will solve my problem ! I appreciate it, really interesting!

Comment: If you've found this answer useful, please consider [upvoting and accepting it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).